# Is that possible to transfer data from IMAP server using Volley Library

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask, android-volley, jakarta-mail

I'm new to Android, developing an email app in android studio and facing a problem when retrieving data from IMAP server to a listview (email inbox) with asynctask.

The data loaded very slowly and it's very annoying. Can you give me some advises how to make the load of data go faster? is that possible to use volley library in this case?

Sorry for very bad English, i hope you are understand. Thanks for your helps.

Comment: I don't think that volley library will speed up your data, it doesn't use magic. Check your server connection speed, your client connection speed, or show your code for us to check if we see something wrong there

Comment: Make sure you're using the [Folder.fetch method](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/Folder.html#fetch-javax.mail.Message:A-javax.mail.FetchProfile-) to bulk load the header/envelope information you need for your list view.

Comment: @VladMatvienko how about pagination or load more in my listview? Can it help? if yes, how to implement load more/pagination in IMAP loading?

Comment: @BillShannon what is difference between Folder.fetch and Folder.open?

Comment: `how to implement load more/pagination in IMAP` looks like a completely different question. Why don't you ask it separately? I can't answer it in context of this question, as they almost not relate.

Comment: What's the difference between a cat and a kangaroo?  Maybe if you quote the parts of the documentation for each method that's confusing you it would be easier to answer your question in a way that you would understand.